# Run javascript variable in Django templates

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, concatenation

I have variable bbb = "youmightalsolike.0.title"; in javascript of django template file. i want to add {{ and }} in variable bbb like i made in aaa for example which runs perfectly with **output 42 which i want**.

```
        var aaa = {{youmightalsolike.0.title}};
        console.log("aaa = "+aaa);              //aaa = 42
```

I have tried using these which was useless. maybe i dont know to concantinate.
Again i dont know what is the exact value so **i cant directly write {{youmightalsolike.0.title}}** cause this value "youmightalsolike.0.title" has to comes from onclick function.

```
        var bbb = "youmightalsolike.0.title";
        console.log("bbb = "+bbb);              //bbb = youmightalsolike.0.title
        var ccc = "{{bbb}}"; 
        console.log("ccc = "+ccc);              //ccc = undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a variable to javascript in a django template, it's really important to add speechmarks where appropriate.

#### If `youmightalsolike.0.title` is a python variable passed down in the context:

The django template language will produce a javascript file exactly as you tell it too. So if `youmightalsolike.0.title` is equal to `"Gladiator"` for example, this will result in (after django has rendered your template):

```
var bbb = "youmightalsolike.0.title"
console.log("bbb = "+bbb);              //bbb = youmightalsolike.0.title
var ccc = Gladiator;            //here you're setting ccc to undefined
console.log("ccc = "+ccc);
```

now unless further up in your javascript you have defined some variable called Gladiator this is why ccc is undefined.

To correct this, what you need to do is:

```
var bbb = "{{youmightalsolike.0.title}}";
```

When rendered, this will result in:

```
var bbb = "gladiator"
```

Which will get you the result you need.

#### Edit: If `youmightalsolike.0.title` comes from a javascript event:

In this case you don't need to use the django template language at all. All of the rendering that django does happens on the server side. It generates some HTML or javascript (or any kind of text really). This is then sent to the client side and loads as a website. Django doesn't touch anything from this point on (apart from API calls), and so anything you want to do with your variables should be pure javascript. You won't be able to use any template variables inside `{{...}}` or template tags.

I'm no longer 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but I hope the above helps.

Comment: I can't use "{{youmightalsolike.0.title}}" cause i dont know that exact string, it's value comes from onclick("youmightalsolike.0.title") function as string.  so please again read the question as i edited. Thanks for replying

Comment: @RoshanOscarSah I have further edited my answer, to hopefully add clarity. I'm not 100% sure what it is you're trying to achieve now. I hope the above helps. Feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: Nup, may be i don't know how to ask question. Can you please help me? I have deadline and i am stuck at this. we can use hangouts meet or zoom or anything. Thank you